# Castle.Windsor per request lifestyle: subcontainers vs custom lifestyle

Tags: castle-windsor

I need a per request lifestyle in Castle.Windsor. This is not an ASP app, and the native PerWebRequest lifestyle will not work.

Before processing a request I do (for every request):

```
MyContainer = new Container();
MyContainer.Register(
    Component.For<ICache>().ImplementedBy<Cache>().LifeStyle.Singleton
    );
MyMainStaticContainer.AddChildContainer(MyContainer);
//MyMainStaticContainer contains implementations which
//can be shared across requests
```

Then somewhere in the code:

```
MyContainer.Resolve<ICache>().Items.Add("x", "y");
...
MyContainer.Resolve<ICache>().Items.Get("x");
```

Finally, when the work is done (in ASP it would be in Application_EndRequest)

```
MyContainer.Parent.RemoveChildContainer(MyContainer);
MyContainer.Dispose();
```

This is quite elegant (as in: not a lot of steps, simple to understand) and it works for me, but I am quite curious if implementing a custom lifestyle would be better (safer?, more efficient?).

Thanks in advance,

Tymek

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "**Transient**"?

This link may help you pick the right one for your needs: **[CastleProject - Lifestyles](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/lifestyles.html)**

**NOTE:**  To save you from registering this on every request, you may want to take advantage of the IDs in the Windsor.config.  IDs will allow you to have multiple implementations of ICache and you can pull them out of Windsor using the Interface-ID composite key.

**in Windsor.config:**

```
<component id="MyDefaultCache"
           service="MyAssembly.ICache, MyAssembly"
           type="MyAssembly.MyDefaultCache, MyAssembly" />
<component id="MySpecialCache" 
           service="MyAssembly.ICache, MySpecialCache"
           type="MySpecialAssembly.MySpecialCache, MySpecialAssembly" />
```

**and in code:**

```
MyContainer.Resolve<ICache>("MySpecialCache")
```

The first one is always default, so **`MyContainer.Resolve<ICache>`** will resolve to **`MyAssembly.MyDefaultCache`**